# Proving the sup norm

Tags: normed-spaces

> Let $D \ne \varnothing$ be a set and $E =(D, \mathbb{R})$ be the vectorspace formed by all bounded functions $f: D \to \mathbb{R}$. Show that $$\|f\| = \sup\{|f(x)| : x \in D\}$$ defines a norm $\|\cdot\|$ in $E$.

So for all $x \in D$ we have that $(1).$ $|(af)(x)| = |af(x)| = |a||f(x)|$ and also $(2).$ if $\|f\| = 0$ then $|f(x)| = 0$ for all $x \in D$. Now only the triangle inequality would be needed to show.

Let $f,g \in E$ and $x \in D.$ Now $|(f+g)(x)| = |f(x)+g(x)| \leqslant |f(x)|+|g(x)|$.

This is what I got for this, however reading the official solution they had the same thing, but for $(1)$ they had added $|a||f(x)| \leqslant \|a\|\|f\|$ and similarly for the triangle inequality they had added $|f(x)|+|g(x)| \leqslant \|f\| + \|g\|$

There was no explanation for this so what might that be stating? $|f(x)|+|g(x)|$ is less than or equal to the supremum of $|f(x)|+|g(x)|$?

Comment: Do you want to know why $|f(x)|+|g(x)|\leq \|f\|+\|g\|$? Or do you want to know why this inequality is needed?

Comment: I would like to know why $|f(x)| + |g(x)| \leqslant ||f|| + ||g||$?

Comment: Because $|f(x)|\leq\|f\|$ and $|g(x)|\leq\|g\|$ for any $x\in D$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For each $x\in D$, $|f(x)|\le  \sup\{|f(y)| : y \in D\}=\|f\|$. Similarly, $|g(x)|\le \|g\|$. Thus $|f(x)|+|g(x)|\le \|f\|+\|g\|$.

Comment: @Nate We want to show that $\|f+g\|\le \|f\| +\|g\|$ for each function $f,g\in E$. This can be concluded as follows.
For each $x\in D$  we have $$|(f+g)(x)| = |f(x)+g(x)| \leqslant |f(x)|+|g(x)|\le \|f\|+\|g\|.$$ So 
$$\|f+g\|=\sup\{|f(x)+g(x)| : x \in D\}\le \sup\{\|f\|+\|g\| : x \in D\}=\|f\|+\|g\|.$$

Comment: Thanks for the answer!